# How to turn off auto build in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to turn off auto build in vs code?
[image]

i use **Competitive Programming Helper extension.**
and c++.

i tried find in setting to off it, find in youtube and another but didn't find solution.

Comment: [Link to the referred extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DivyanshuAgrawal.competitive-programming-helper) for those like me who don't know it.

Comment: You can look through [the extension's settings](https://github.com/agrawal-d/cph/blob/main/package.json) if you want to investigate yourself whether it provides any to change this. Consider asking also as a GitHub issue ticket / discussion item.

Comment: @b264 Please add the *screenshot* of something being built (likely in Terminals or Output panel). Otherwise it's hard to say.

Comment: @Dimava this isn't my question, but I am curious how to turn off ALL building

Comment: @b264 There are extensions that build for you on open (like Vite), task settings to "run task on folder open", and maybe some other settings . The proper answer would be, probably, "Use `Bisect Extentions` to find which extension does that, and either uninstall it or fix its settings" (use `Restart w/o exts` before that to make sure it's caused by ext, otherwise check tasks in .vscode or .vscode-workspace )

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR It doesn't look like it's possible without modifying the source.

Luckily this is an open-source plug-in, and you can view the source.  If you look at the config.ts file here (https://github.com/agrawal-d/cph/blob/7f2d2728fec88b0a0e707074f66eede7eb7048d3/src/config.ts#L45C25-L45C25) you'll see that there is indeed a config setting called `skipCompile` which defines a list of filename extensions for which it will SKIP auto-compile.  The only value in the list at present is `*.py` which makes sense.

If you wanted to, I'm sure you could take this plug-in, modify this line in the config.ts, and rebuild the source into a new `dist/extension.js` file you can install.

This setting could almost certainly be easily exposed as a configurable setting, AND you could provide a feature for future users!

You can find the open-source project for this plug-in here: https://github.com/agrawal-d/cph