# How to enable Auto Build or Auto Debug in VS Code for C++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm currently Using Ubuntu and VS Code. (Version 1.86.2) and I'm trying to learn to code in C++

Extensions installed are currently: C/C++ ; C/C++ Extension Pack ; C/C++ Themes ; CMake ; CMake Tools

A lot of things are working Fine but I notice that I Have to take this exact approach to get Problems identified in the "Problems" Tab.

Exact Approach:

Terminal -> Run Task -> Build Active File

This is mostly okay, but I have seen a Tutorial where the Problems are populated before the User Clicks Run or Anything.

I just want to know where I can find the option to turn on and off as I see fit.

This is the Video: https://youtu.be/8jLOx1hD3_o?t=6473

You'll see it within a minute of the timestamp provided. Around the 1 Hour and 48 minute mark.

Other solutions and questions have been provided before but for some reason those options and settings aren't visible or available to me:

[How to turn off auto build in vs code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75157523/how-to-turn-off-auto-build-in-vs-code)

This Guide calls is Hot Reload:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue?view=vs-2022

https://superuser.com/questions/135627/visual-studio-not-auto-building-when-i-press-the-debug-button

I was expecting to be able to see those options listed above and be able to click/Toggle on and off.

Comment: if you have cmake tools, why are you using the "build active file" task? also, not all c++ toolchains support hot reload. I think MSVC 2022 does. what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you want to have this "Problems" tab in the terminal in VS:Code?

- try right click next to these tabs to add the "Problems" tab.

And Hot Reload is something else. Hot Reload lets you Debug the program while its Running. Or in other words, you can add one feature with out debugging the whole program.